# Checking a remote host (Linux) hard disk space

Tags: python, linux, shutil

I need to check the available hard disk space for a remote linux host in Python.

Currently i am using shutil to check the same on my host.

import shutil
total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("D:/")

Comment: you may use some ssh library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [ssh](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/command) to execute commands on the remote machine. `paramiko` is one library that provides ssh functions. Sample code:

```py
from paramiko import SSHClient

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
# more options found at https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html
# ssh.connect(ip,port,username,password)
ssh.connect('serverip', username='youruser')  # using ssh keys
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('df -h /')
outlines = ssh_stdout.readlines()
resp = ''.join(outlines)
print(resp)
```

Alternatively you can setup some monitor service in the remote server, and use some convenient webpages or api to get the information. but that requires more resources.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, here as answer:
If you are on a linux system you can use simply an os call, no need to include a new library.

```
import os
stream = os.popen('ssh host@target "df -h"')
output = stream.read()
```